# About Page For Internal Web Application

Tags: language-agnostic

What do you typically include?  Right now we're just thinking about the server it's hosted on and application version.  What else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The About page is useful a place to put information about the currently logged user which might be useful for debugging purposes.  So username, and user groups they're in, any roles they have and so on.  You could also put their IP address, OS and Brower version there if you think you'd need it and your users wouldn't be able to reliably work this out by themselves.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add a little database connectivity test as well, but you might not want to force the user to be logged in.